# Celery fast event loop for checking for running tasks?

Tags: python, celery

```
#ready is populated with some obj
ready = set()
running = []
while ready or running:
    #send all tasks in ready
    while ready:
        #send celery task
        t = ready.pop()
        res = add.delay(t)
        running[res] = t

    while running:
         if breakout:
             break

         for run in running.iterkeys():
             if run.ready():
                 rtask = running[run]
                 result = run.get(interval=0.00001)
                 # put dependent tasks into ready
                 if rtask.depends:
                     for t in rtask.depends:
                         ready.add(t)

                 del running[run]
                 # we have tasks in ready now so break out of running and send out ready jobs
                 breakout = True
                 break
```

As tasks get bigger, my code spent way too much time checking for running tasks for completion which make sense because it's O(N)

Is there a faster way to check for completion of tasks sent to celery workers?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you really need to check running tasks? You could make a logic which does something upon task completion. For example, you could make a decorator.

Also, if you still wanna maintain list of tasks - I recommend using mapping (dict) instead of list. Every task has uuid which can be mapped to the value (for instance, True). It will help checking whether the task is running - faster, and will still provide the ability to iterate over the keys. Also, it allows to easily remove the items by assigning the False value and then removing the item at the next iteration (instead of making breakouts and N*(N-1) operation in case of all your tasks have completed.